# Python:I get that error while trying ot parse the response of a post request

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
with open("File.txt", 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('https://file.io/?expires=1m', files=f)
print(r.status_code)
print(r)
```

The site is that one https://www.file.io/, but I get that error.

```
    too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Check the updated answer as it is working for me, please comment back in case of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I went through the api of file.io, you have submit the data as **multipartform data**.

**Approach 1=Using requests module**

```
multipart_form_data = {
    'file': ('File.txt', open('File.txt', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('https://file.io', files=multipart_form_data)
```

you can change the url to `https://file.io/?expires=1w` to make it expire in a week

**Approch 2-Using Curl**

```
curl -F "file=@File.txt" https://file.io
```

F represents multi part form data